# C++ program works on XP SP2 only after installing Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-xp

I have a C++ program. It's quite simple - shows an image (splash screen) and launches another application, then closes when that other application is started. Actually, this one: http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/A-better-WPF-splash-screen.aspx with very minor changes (my splash screen image and my program is launched instead of the sample one).

It works good on my Windows 7 developer machine. Also it works on another (virtual) machine with Windows XP SP2 and Visual Studio 2008 installed. But it doesn't work on just the same virtual Windows XP SP2 machine without Visual Studio. It shows an error: "Entry point memmove_s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll".

I have found that a problem possible is in WindowsCodec DLL (no such DLL in clear XP SP2 installation, but it is in Windows/system32 folder of XP SP2 with Visual Studio) so I copied it to the application folder on the clear system. After that the program partially works (launches another application after start) but didn't show the splash screen image.

Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package (both 2008 and 2010) didn't help.

I've found a recommendation to use static linking in Visual Studio (**Multi Threaded (/MT)** option in project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation), but it also didn't help.

Also I have tried DependencyWalker but cannot find any differences in dependencies for both test systems.

Anyone have any ideas why this could happen? I'm completely new in C++, hope this is something obvious that I just don't know...

Comment: Run `depends` on your executable and find out why it needs that DLL.

Comment: Perhaps using a cross-platform toolkit like Qt might be worthwhile....

Comment: Do you mean DependencyWalker? I've tried it but couldn't understand why it works on system with Visual Studio, but don't work without. The dependencies look exactly the same and the same missing dependencies and dependencies with missing functions.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch unfortunately I have no experience in C++ so rewriting the program is not possible for me. Hope it needs just some configuring...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Even if you use cross-platform toolkit, your program will still depend on platform-specific components. Compile Qt with msvc, and your program will be dependent on VC redist x86 and won't work if it isn't installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has a dependency on the .NET framework, at least version 3.0.  That is not available on an XP SP2 install by default.  If you don't see windowscodecs.dll then you didn't install the proper version of .NET.  This does work when you install VS2008 because it also installs .NET.

The download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22).

Comment: Exactly! Installed .NET framework 3.5 and the splash screen is shown now. The problem is that my application targeting .NET 2.0 (it seems to be more general on client computers now)... but if understand right, nothing can be done without rewriting the program or installing framework.

Answer (score 1):

C++ programs become dependent the specific versions of the crt library that it was compiled on.  If the running system does not have that version in the either the local program directory, or the systems WinSxS directory.  This is a specific issue with C++ progams compiled using VS 2005 or 2008.  See here for more information : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly

You might see this problem go away if you use VS 2010, as it uses a different method for dependency resolution.

Comment: Actually since the question is referencing WPF, it's clear that it is .NET. Still your answer is generally correct, though the runtime here is not the C runtime. +1

Comment: His specific error mentions a dll that is part of the CRT.  Regardless of your framework, if you're using any of the C libraries, you're using the CRT.

Comment: He's using managed C++, which would make this .NET-based. But don't worry my upvote was well-deserved, because your answer contains the gist (and more) :)